# Compiling C++ on Windows (Mingw / Cygwin)

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I'm trying to compile my first c++11 file for a school project, but I'm getting several errors in both cygwin and mingw environments, Maybe I'm missing some part I need to install but this should be a pretty straightforward thing. Alas, I know nothing of C++ compiling so I have no idea where to start looking.

This is the output i get:

```
g++  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast  -std=c++11    -c -o date.o date.cc
In file included from date.cc:6:0:
date.h: In constructor ‘Date::Date(int, int, int)’:
date.h:20:6: warning: ‘Date::day’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
  int day;   // the day (1-..)
      ^
date.h:19:6: warning:   ‘int Date::month’ [-Wreorder]
  int month; // the month (1-12)
      ^
date.cc:24:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
 Date::Date(int y, int m, int d) : year(y), day(d), month(m) {}
 ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from date.cc:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/move.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = const Date]’:
date.cc:77:13:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:176:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const Date’ and ‘std::remove_reference<const                                              Date&>::type {aka const Date}’)
       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:176:11: note: candidates are:
In file included from date.cc:6:0:
date.h:9:7: note: Date& Date::operator=(const Date&) <near match>
 class Date {
       ^
date.h:9:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const Date*’ to ‘Date*’
date.h:9:7: note: Date& Date::operator=(Date&&)
date.h:9:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<const Date&>::type {aka const Date}’ to ‘Date&&’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from date.cc:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:177:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const Date’ and ‘std::remove_reference<const                                              Date&>::type {aka const Date}’)
       __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:177:11: note: candidates are:
In file included from date.cc:6:0:
date.h:9:7: note: Date& Date::operator=(const Date&) <near match>
 class Date {
       ^
date.h:9:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const Date*’ to ‘Date*’
date.h:9:7: note: Date& Date::operator=(Date&&)
date.h:9:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<const Date&>::type {aka const Date}’ to ‘Date&&’
<builtin>: recipe for target 'date.o' failed
make: *** [date.o] Error 1
```

Here's the header file:

```
/*
 * class Date: describes dates with year, month, and day. Doesn't
 * handle leap years.
 */

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date {
public:
    Date();                    // today's date
    Date(int y, int m, int d); // yyyy-mm-dd
    int get_year() const;      // get the year
    int get_month() const;     // get the month
    int get_day() const;       // get the day
    void next();               // advance to next day
private:
    int year;  // the year (four digits)
    int month; // the month (1-12)
    int day;   // the day (1-..)
    static int daysPerMonth[12]; // number of days in each month
};

/*
 * Prints a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd. The function is intended to
 * show an example of a global function; it would be better to overload
 * the output operator <<.
 */
void print(const Date& d);

/*
 * This function is an overloaded operator <. It makes it possible
 * to compare two dates d1 and d2 with 'd1 < d2'.
 */
bool operator<(const Date& d1, const Date& d2);

/*
 * A function to compute the number of days between two dates.
 */
int distance(const Date& d1, const Date& d2);

#endif
```

And my cc file:

```
/*
 * Class Date, implementation.
 * The next() function in this implementation cannot handle leap years.
 */

#include "date.h"

#include <ctime>   /* for C routines time and localtime */
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> /* for swap */

using namespace std;

int Date::daysPerMonth[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

Date::Date() {
    time_t timer = time(0); // time in seconds since 1970-01-01
    tm* locTime = localtime(&timer); // broken-down time
    year = 1900 + locTime->tm_year;
    month = 1 + locTime->tm_mon;
    day = locTime->tm_mday;
}

Date::Date(int y, int m, int d) : year(y), day(d), month(m) {}

int Date::get_year() const {
    return year;
}

int Date::get_month() const {
    return month;
}

int Date::get_day() const {
    return day;
}

void Date::next() {
    if(month == 12 && day == daysPerMonth[month-1] ){ 
        day=1;
        month = 1;
        year++;
    } else if (month == daysPerMonth[month-1]) {
        month++;
        day = 1;
    } else if(day < daysPerMonth[month-1]){ 
        day++;  
    }
}

void print(const Date& d) {
    cout << d.get_year() << "-";
    if (d.get_month() < 10) { 
        cout << "0";
    }
    cout << d.get_month() << "-";
    if (d.get_day() < 10) {
        cout << "0";
    }
    cout << d.get_day();
}

bool operator<(const Date& d1, const Date& d2) {
    return (d1.get_year() < d2.get_year()) ||
    (d1.get_year() == d2.get_year() && d1.get_month() < d2.get_month()) ||
    (d1.get_year() == d2.get_year() && d1.get_month() == d2.get_month()
     && d1.get_day() < d2.get_day());
}


int distance(const Date& d1, const Date& d2) {

    Date date1 = d1;
    Date date2 = d2;
    int total = 0;
    if ( d2 < d1 ){
        swap(d1,d2);
    }
    while( date1 < date2){
        date1.next();
        total++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Is there anything I've forgotten about?

This is the first exercise in the course and should be very straightforward - which leads me to believe that the header and make files are correct..

Regards

Comment: same failure with mingw? what is your g++ -version?

Comment: Yes same failure.

Cygwin: 
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)

mingw:
gcc version 4.9.2 (tdm64-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int distance(const Date& d1, const Date& d2) {
    /* ... code ... */
        swap(d1,d2);
    /* ... code ... */
}
```

Your issue is that `d1` and `d2` are both `const reference` types. Because they're reference, they could be moved *if they can be modified*. However, because they're `const`, you are not allowed to modify them. That means that they can neither be moved nor `swap()`ed.

Perhaps you meant to swap `date1` and `date2`?